# Regex to get "sortable" chapters from contract chapter numbers

Tags: regex

i am looking for a regular expression to sort chapters of a contract. Therefore i want to transform this chapter numbering to a 2-digit format "`dd.dd.dd`". Chapters are e.g.:

```
1.
1.2.1
...
2.10.4
```

Chapter numbering:

- 1 - 3 digit sections possible
- each section can have 1 or 2 digits
- dots are optional

My way:

- regex first digits: "`\d+\.`"
- regex second digits: "`\.\d+\.?`"
- third digits are extracted with a `split()` function.
- i then assemble the 3 sections to a 2-digit-format (e.g. `02.10.04`).

Problem:

- my solution seems not very safe. Because sometimes a dot is used after a digit section, sometimes it is not.
- maybe there is an easier way to simply "format"

Thanks for your support!

Regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    (?<=\.|^)(\d)(?=\.|$)
Replace: 0$1
```

This regex pattern will capture all single digit path values which are sandwiched on both sides by either dots, or the start/end of the string.  The replacement prepends a leading zero to make the digits have a width of two.  Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1rQZqG/1) showing that the logic is working.